# EmberJS - How to pass data from a component back to the route?

Tags: ember.js

How do you pass data from a component action, back to a route. For example, I have a component for a custom select field. When the select option changes, I want to update the form model. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass action when declaring component in template and then call this action via `this.sendAction()` in component's action.

For example, route template:

```
{{my-component action='updateModel'}}
```

Component action:

```
actions: {
  changeOccured(newValue) {
    this.sendAction('action', newValue);
  }
}
```

Of course you also need `updateModel` action declared in route or controller which accepts `newValue` as parameter and updates form model.